# Symfony2 Doctrine: Entity Listener, Why only preFlush working?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

At the begginig sorry for my poor english :)

I have in app/config/services.yml:

```
page_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\PageListener
        arguments: [ "@service_container" ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

in AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Page.orm.yml:

```
entityListeners:
    PageListener:
        postFlush: [postFlush]
        preFlush: [preFlush]
```

in AppBundle\Entity\PageListener:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

class PageListener
{
    public function __construct($container){ /* nothing here */ }

    public function preFlush(Page $page, PreFlushEventArgs $event){ ... }

    public function postFlush(Page $page, PostFlushEventArgs $event){ ... }
}
```

Now when i do

```
$em->persist($page);
$em->flush();
```

`preFlush` do what have to do, but `postFlush` not event start :/ Even when i put exit, or something like that in `postFlush` nothing happens.

Do I forget something or what? Any suggestions?

Comment: postFlush is not a Lifecycle callback. It belongs to UnityOfWork

Answer (score 1):

I don't have full idea about it but still I know you need to define event when you are registering the event.

```
  my.listener2:

    class: Acme\SearchBundle\EventListener\SearchIndexer2

    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, connection: default }
```

kindly refer this link:

http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony2-event-listeners/

Comment: Didn't work. For now ive replaced `PostFlush` by `postUpdate` in this case it will do the same thing. But i dont find any answer why `postFlush` dont work :/

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your Symfony or Doctrine version. Paste your composer.json